# C# .Net Core application: ReadKey from multiple threads

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, console

I have a simple question, how to read a console application key from multiple threads without affecting the buffer state? in my application i have a main thread which always checks for a pressed F1..F5 key, and in my second thread i need to get the user data, for example "username", the problem here is that the main thread blocks the second thread from getting the character pressed, such as when the main thread calls `Console.ReadKey();` it affects the state of the buffer, so in case an 'A' character is pressed the character will not be propagated to the second thread, is there a fix for that?

Is there is a way to detect F1 key in the main thread without affecting the console buffer state?

Comment: You shouldn't do this.   Your main UI thread should read all keys, then pass messages to the other threads to carry out the work.  Either via queues or lists or flags, or delegates or anything.

Comment: In the main thread I am reading characters key by key, and in my second thread I want to do something like Console.ReadLine(); let's say that I have a list of ConsoleKeyInfo and every time I get a key I append this List, how can I create a string from this List<ConsoleKeyInfo>, taking into account that this may contain arrows keys, delete key, ...etc.

Comment: Again, only your main UI thread should read from and write to the console.  Any background thread should not contain any code that accesses the console directly.   Don't send 'ConsoleKeyInfo' messages, in you main thread, work out what a keypress actually means, create a message class that contains the intent of the command, as send THAT to the background thread.

Comment: As an example, your background thread should not be 'sent' a keypress F1, it should be sent the command 'Help', your UI should not send F5, it should send the command 'Refresh'.   Does that make sense?

Comment: let's say that in the main thread you want to get the user age, usually you are going to do something like this: int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int age); let's say now that you want at the same time, and at every moment detect an F1 key, what are you going to do in this case?

Comment: You can't do that in a console app.  You will have to implement your own method of performing user input, character by character, and either building up a string (to then pass to int.TryParse), or detecting one of the special keys (ConsoleKey..F1, ConsoleKey.F2 etc).

Comment: Any idea how can I convert List<ConsoleKeyInfo> to string?